# Render SSRS report in PDF format in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have some deployed SSRS reports on the server. Now I am accessing those reports from my ASP.NET application. After some research I found that default print button of the ReportViewer will not be visible in Chrome or any web browser except Internet Explorer. So all I want to render the Reports in PDF format so user can take the print out of PDF format without saving the file. Here's the piece of code I am using:

```
IReportServerCredentials irsc = DBConnection.NetworkCredentials();
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = irsc;
List<ReportParameter> list = new List<ReportParameter>();
list.Add(new ReportParameter("ref_no", refNo));
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(list);
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Render("PDF");
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Refresh();
```

But its not working. The reports are getting rendered but not in PDF format. And if someone take the print out, alignment of all the fields like Tablix, TextBox are not properly aligned. Does any one know how can I do this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain "not working" in more detail.

Comment: @Jongware , have explained the issue in more detail. Please have a look now and let me know if still not clear. Thank you for your concern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fortunately, after so many try, have found the solution. This is what I have done:

```
IReportServerCredentials irsc = DBConnection.NetworkCredentials();
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = irsc;

List<ReportParameter> list = new List<ReportParameter>();
list.Add(new ReportParameter("ref_no", refNo));
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(list);
byte[] data = ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Render("pdf");
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=Manifest_Print.pdf");
Response.BinaryWrite(data);
```

And it worked for me.

Comment: if that worked, you can go ahead and mark your own answer as the correct answer :).

Comment: Exactly what I needed. I just needed the Render pdf part.

Comment: Can I instantiate ReportViewer1 in C# without rendering it in the Browser?